# Node axios returns empty status and curl return 200 for tiktok

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

**Axios**

I am sending the request to this [image URL](https://images.thebetwaygroup.com/umbraco/umbracobetway/media/6882235/logoheader-betway.png) using Axios. It returns a status of 200
But for TikTok [image URL](https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-alisg-p-0037/213536d641064ff7a8c160164f7d289c_1610544424?x-expires=1610730000&x-signature=wdpLWkCwl%2BW4rA2BYYu2yLUVCi0%3D), it returns empty status.

**Curl**

When I send the request from curl to the TikTok [image URL](https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-alisg-p-0037/213536d641064ff7a8c160164f7d289c_1610544424?x-expires=1610730000&x-signature=wdpLWkCwl%2BW4rA2BYYu2yLUVCi0%3D), I received 200 status

**Problem**

Why Axios did not show any status for TikTok when the request is hit

**Trying**

I also set the headers but it's not working. You can send the request one by one both links in
the code

**Code**

```
 'use strict';


 const axios     = require('axios'); 
 const rp     = require('request');

async function getStatus() {
try {

//tiktok link status empty 
var link = encodeURI('https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-alisg-p-0037/213536d641064ff7a8c160164f7d289c_1610544424?x-expires=1610730000&x-signature=wdpLWkCwl%2BW4rA2BYYu2yLUVCi0%3D');

//other image link status 200 
// var link = encodeURI('https://images.thebetwaygroup.com/umbraco/umbracobetway/media/6882235/logoheader-betway.png');

var result = await axios.get(link,{
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.80 Safari/537.36',
        Referer: 'https://www.tiktok.com/',
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-type' : 'image/png',

    }
}); 

console.log(result)

} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
}


getStatus()
```

Comment: Curl returns HTTP 403 (Access Denied, forbidden) for me. It's probably a permissions issue. Not familiar with TikTok but the expires and signature query parameters look like they're providing authentication credentials which may expire.

Comment: might be link expired

Comment: Try this [url](https://p16-sign-sg.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/dc3dd88c8fd1403fb0d26709848d9a1d?x-expires=1610971200&x-signature=oOzt5s8hAS1X6p7RFPTzKK3mns8%3D). It might be expired after 12 hours

Comment: New link is still a 403 for me :(